# Calculating number of abelian groups up to isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

$Problem$

Let p<sub>1</sub>,......,p<sub>n</sub> be distinct primes. Up to isomorphism ,how many Abelian groups are there of order p<sub>1</sub><sup>4</sup>p<sub>2</sub><sup>4</sup>....p<sub>n</sub><sup>4</sup>

$ Attempt$

Each p<sub>i</sub><sup>4</sup> can be partitioned into 5 ways. So total number of Abelian groups is 5<sup>n</sup>

Is my approach correct ?

Comment: Yes${}{}{}{}{}$.

Comment: Thanks.........

Answer (score 1):

Consider $2^4$...  You can have  $\mathbb Z_{2^4},\mathbb Z_2×\mathbb Z_{2^3},\mathbb Z_2×\mathbb Z_2×\mathbb Z_{2^2},\mathbb Z_{2^2}×\mathbb Z_{2^2}$, or $\mathbb Z_2×\mathbb Z_2×\mathbb Z_2×\mathbb Z_2$... Thus you have $5$ different groups of order $2^4$.

Yes, the number of partitions of $4$ is apparently $5$:  $4,1+3,1+1+2,2+2$ and $1+1+1+1$.

So you have $5^n$ such abelian groups.